# how can I install Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition on Windows 8.1

Tags: sql-server-2005, installation, sql-server-express, windows-8

[image]

I can't install Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Add the specific error or issue you got during installation. Otherwise, it's a vague question and will probably be closed.

Comment: So how do you expect we would help you without log files and more concrete information. Please dont post fragment questions if you post complete question you would get quick and correct answer. Now tell about problem in details. Share log file for failed installation here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Microsoft Official document

SQL Server 2005 (the release version and service packs) and earlier versions of SQL Server are not supported on Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2012, Windows 8.1, or Windows 8. You will receive a warning in the Action Center if Windows 8.1 or Windows 8 detects an instance of SQL Server 2005.

To resolve this issue, upgrade or remove the existing instance of SQL Server 2005.

Please read below link

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2681562/en-gb

EDIT:

Click on run the program without getting help. It will proceed. Although installation is not supported it would not block you from installing but you are doing it at your own risk. If you want a supported scenario. You can create a VM on windows 8 machine and can install windows server 2003 SP2 on it and then install SQL Server 2005 with SP4 to run supported scenario.

Comment: Yeah but I have to do my project with only SQL 2005, no other version are allowed, and my computer is 8.1. So, can u guys help me to solve this compatible issues plsss.

Comment: Click on run the program without getting help. It will proceed. Although installation is not supported it would not block you from installing but you are doing it at your own risk.I have updated my answer as well

Comment: It works now, I run the exe from command prompt as admin and it totally works on window 8.1. :) Thank u for ur answers guys. :)

Answer (score 1):

Eduardo Molteni asked this in 2012 for running on Windows 8 (not 8.1) and came back a few days later with his solution. You might give it a try.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520551/how-to-install-sql-server-2005-express-in-windows-8

The secret sauce, according to Eduardo is:

> After you run the install file SQLExpr.exe look for a hidden folder recently created in the C drive. Copy the contents to another folder and cancel the installer (or use WinRar to open the file and extract the contents to a temp folder)
>
> After that, find the file sqlncli_x64.msi in the setup folder, and run it.
>
> Now you are ready the run the setup.exe file and install SQL server 2005 without errors

I have not done this myself, since I have no need, but it seems possible.  Check the other entries in the thread as well.

Comment: It works now, I run the exe from command prompt as admin and it totally works on window 8.1. :) Thank u for ur answers guys. :)